# Android: Use FLAG_FULLSCREEN and TYPE_KEYGUARD together

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I'm trying to do an Android-Tablet app for presentations on trade fairs etc. I don't want to upload the app to the app store, only use it on my tablet.

I try to run the app in ful screen mode (without status bar) with:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Works great. I try to disable the home button with:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

in my OnCreate-Method. Works great.

But if I try to use both in one app, only disabling the home button still works, any idea what i can do about this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you found the answer already, I´m facing the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not, still searching for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the activity as fullscreen in AndroidManifest.xml, and then doing what you already do to capture the home button

```
<activity android:name="..." android:label="..."
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```